# Increase Pop Limit - Age of Empires 1 Definitive Edition

Tags: age-of-empires

I know you were able to increase the pop limit in single player campaigns with some mods and some commands in the start up of the game, but is this possible with AOE Definitive Edition? I've tried looking online but it doesn't seem as if anyone has asked/found a way to do this.

Comment: silly question, have you tried the old commands

Comment: @KevinFischer, why is it a silly question? I have tried the old commands, doesn't work.

Comment: As of right now, doesn't look as if there is a way to increase the population limit.  Apparently on multiplayer it's at 300